# How to Bind data to a Textblock which is of type "\xe449" using a ttf file?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

am developing a WP 8.1 app using C# and xaml.
To display Icons am using ttf file which contains some codes to display the icons.
When i give the static data to a Textblock then it is displaying the icon (in XAML i have wrote like this)

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Foreground="{Binding STYLE.IOS.ICOLOR}" 
                                          Text="&#xe91d;"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" 
                                           FontFamily="ms-appx:/Assets/Fonts/some-font.ttf#some-font">

                    </TextBlock>
```

am able to view the icon. 
My problem is the icon text will be coming from a service so am filling it to a string and Binding the data as Below

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Foreground="{Binding STYLE.IOS.ICOLOR}" 
                                          Text="{Binding STYLE.IOS.ICON}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" 
                                           FontFamily="ms-appx:/Assets/Fonts/some-font.ttf#some-font">

                    </TextBlock>
```

Am unable to view the icon i can just read the code  which is \xe449
(If you want to display the icon from the code behind we need to include \x before to the code)
And if i statically assign the value to ICON from the code behind as (ICON = "\xe449") i can able to see the icon. The problem here is when am binding the data from a service and concatenating to that variable (@"\x" + ICON) it is not displaying. 
Can someone please help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to bind your text with result of this - WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xe91d;")

Comment: Hey Thanks a ton for your reply Chirag.. Thank you so much